# Update DataGrid on item change with Caliburn Micro

Tags: mvvm, datagrid, caliburn

I have a datagrid which is bound to a collection of items using Caliburn Micro. I would like the grid to update as soon as a user makes an edit on each row. I would think this would be simple (like ASP.NET simple) but I haven't found anything that seems to work.

Here is my ViewModel

```
public class JournalViewModel :    Caliburn.PresentationFramework.PropertyChangedBase
{
    private CrystalRptDataEntities ctx = new CrystalRptDataEntities();
    private BindableCollection<EmployeeInfo> employees;

    public JournalViewModel()
    {
        Load();        

    }

    public void Load()
    {
        employees = new BindableCollection<EmployeeInfo>(ctx.EmployeeInfoes);
        AllEmployees = employees;
    }

    public BindableCollection<EmployeeInfo> AllEmployees
    {
        get { return employees; }
        set 
        {
            employees = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AllEmployees);
        }
    }

    //....
}
```

Here is my view

```
<DataGrid x:Name="AllEmployees"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to my own question - it took 3 things.

1) I had to add this method to my JournalViewModel class

```
public void SaveChanges()
{
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

2) Then I had to add these 2 references to my xaml file

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;
assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"          
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
```

3) Then I had to attach an Event to my Datagrid like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="AllEmployees"  
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          cal:Message.Attach="[Event CellEditEnding]=[Action SaveChanges()]">
```

That way every time I finished editing a cell, the ctx gets saved.